# installed texlive but am still unable to tex

Tags: installation, tex

The "latex" command is available, but when trying to use it on a Scientific Linux 7.2 system, I get

```
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

(and "ls -R" works).  What do I need to do?

I had done a yum install texlive.x86_64 .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Scientific Linux, but in Ubuntu, the 'fmtutil.cnf" file is found in the 'texlive-base' package.

Try to look for a package that has a similar name...

Comment: Thank you -- unfortunately I get "texlive-base-2012-38.20130427_r30134.el7.noarch already installed and latest version" so that doesn't appear to fix things.  Sigh.

Comment: Did you see what they did on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288200/i-cant-find-the-format-file-latex-fmt?  `fmtutil-sys --all` might be worth trying...

Comment: No, so I just tried it:

    fmtutil-sys --all
    tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
    fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
 </code>

Unfortunately still no dice.  I've removed and installed texlive to no benefit.  Next -- copy <code>/usr/share/texmf from a working tex installation (its SL6.3).